# Python: How to get cosine similarity matrix efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, gensim, cosine-similarity

There are 2 arrays containing 30,000 vectors and 50000 vectors respectively.

```
Item_array = [item1,item2,...,item30000]
User_array = [user1,user2,...,user50000]
```

Each vector in array is the tfidf value using Gensim.

For example:

```
Item_array[0] = [(0, 0.03663947221807151),(2, 0.09781584692664856),(10, 0.07212302141012294)]
```

I'm trying to build a item-user matrix for sorting each user's similar items.
For-loop method cost me lots of time to finish it.

How should i handle this efficiently. Any help should be appreciable..

It's my expected output:

```
           user1 user2 user3 ... user50000
item1      0.35  0.45  0.86        0.46
item2      0.42  0.32  0.53        0.53          
item3      0.65  0.33  0.45        0.46        
...        ...   ...   ...         ... 
item50000  0.54  0.33  0.00        1.00
```

Comment: DId you take a look at [Numpy Matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)?

Comment: @Fabien note that most people advise against using numpy _matrices_, since they have a few localized advantages and a lot of disadvantages compared to numpy _arrays_. Is there a specific advantage of numpy matrices you have in mind?

Comment: @Fabien I don't profess to be a numpy expert but everything I read suggests that they don't want anyone using `np.matrix`.

Comment: Hey, sorry I meant arrays but had matrices in mind while doing the search for the link. Yes, [Numpy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) are better.

Comment: You should be using `numpy.array`s, and try [`sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html) and use `n_jobs=-1` argument to take advantage of a multicore architecture. If you use a properly built `numpy` then this is about as fast as you are going to get.